# Switch between PHP versions on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: php, macos, osx-mountain-lion

Is it possible to have multiple versions of PHP installed on OS X Mountain Lion and freely change between them? Similar to the way MAMP allows you to. I'm wanting to get out of using MAMP and this is really the only feature holding me back.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to get out of using MAMP?

Comment: I had a couple issues setting up vhosts on MAMP though was able to get that sorted a few days ago. I think I'm also just curious about how to set up a dev environment without using a pre packaged solution.

Comment: I also just learned that the newest versions of MAMP only give you PHP 5.2 and 5.4. I'd need to purchase MAMP Pro if I still wanted 5.3.

Answer (score 9):

Even if I may get downvotes for this answer, I think I have to post it for the benefit of the OP.

Surely there is a way to achieve what you want, but you will lose a lot of time.

I often develop web applications on my OSX box and guess what... I use a **Debian virtual machine** to test them on a Webserver. It's easier, faster, neater. I don't need MacPorts to install even four different versions of PHP, I can test all the `pecl` extensions compiling them with a simple command. I can simulate any possible Linux server environment with just a few commands in the virtual machine console, without hacking the sources to make them work under OSX, and without screwing anything up.

Comment: +1, after years of fiddling with local Apache and PHP installations for development on my mac I now just use VirtualBox to run Ubuntu (through the wonderful vagrant project).

Comment: Nice trick; being afraid of downvotes, stating that and getting upvotes…

Comment: +1, I myself have a Linux server in my local network that I'm using. There are many benefits to it, especially when it comes to custom stuff like CoffeeScript, RoR, SASS, etc. 

Only problem might be the performance though when running a virtual install. When running Photoshop, PHPstorm, Sourcetree, browsers, etc on my laptop it can sometimes get a bit slow even without running a virtual OS.

Comment: @nerdklers: yes, this is the drawback.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone wanting to do it with Homebrew:
After successfully installing different versions of php (or any program versions) on can switch between them from the command line:

```
brew unlink php53 && brew link php54
```

Some more tips here:
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Tips-N%27-Tricks